# Set-Cookie Response Header not setting cookie? Possible path issue

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, cookies, setcookie

I have a page:

http://localhost:4201/login

Which, when the user hits login, makes a request to:

http://localhost:4201/api/login/authenticate

Which is then proxied to:

https://myserver.com/xms_webapp_dev10/login/authenticate

Whose response contains the following `set-cookie` response header:

> set-cookie: JSESSIONID=B82FB6A0B9E66E822977F954A5ACB14B; Path=/xms_webapp_dev10; HttpOnly

The problem is that the cookie is not getting set on the client browser. This exact same code works in different environments. The only difference I can see between a working environment and this one is the Path value of the cookie. In a working environment Path=/ but here it is Path=/xms_webapp_dev10

Given this setup, any thoughts on why path might be causing an issue or what the problem might be?

Does the path http://localhost:4201/login need to contain /xms_webapp_dev10?

Or is some other URL wrong? Or something totally different is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie *is* set, but only for requests on path `/xml_webapp_dev10`, therefore you will never see it sent with a request made to `/api/...`. When proxying requests, you must change the cookie paths if you want the cookies to be sent by your browser.